# How to use term with wildcard in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, wildcard, aster

'Terms' and 'Wildcard' is provided by Elasticsearch. 'Terms' is search for multiple OR conditions:

```
        {
          "terms": {
           "IP": [
              "192.168.100.11",
              "192.168.100.13"
            ]
          }
```

'Wildcard'  is recognized by the * (star):

```
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "IP": "192.168.*.11"
          }
```

I want to merge 'wildcard' + 'terms' functions. How can I do that? For example:

```
        {
          "wildcard": {
           "IP": [
              "192.168.*.11",
              "192.168.*.13"
            ]
          }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `bool`'s `should` part, I don't think there is a "terms" like query for `wildcard` and `should` behaves like an `OR`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"wildcard": {"IP": "192.168.*.11"}},
        {"wildcard": {"IP": "192.168.*.13"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei Stefan!